# How can I change the color of the progress bar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, progress-bar

I am interested to find a possibility to change the color of the progress bar in Windows 10 (Anniversary). I've tried [this](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/62851-Blue-Progress-Bars-build-10240?p=1094342&viewfull=1#post1094342) solution but there are some limitations, in the taskbar, the progress color is still green.

Also I've found an [app](http://resource.dopus.com/download/file.php?id=3917&sid=9fadde99ac0d5a3d0f8c6a561343edfd) that let me view the whole picture but I am not sure where should I do the modifications, I can't find where are these value stored.

How can I change the color of the progress bar?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I adjusted your question to meet site standards. For future reference, please don't put tags in the title and always ask a specific question. Asking "Any thoughts" is too vague and leads to misunderstanding of your true meaning. For more information, read **[ask]**.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, You cant change the progress bar like you can do on Windows 7. So my advice will be stay tuned for future updates which may include changing the color of progress bar

Comment: Indeed, in win 7, it can be done using some tweaks (but not native). Thanks